# Bin datetime range using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that consists of a operation id and a datetime stamp for the Start and End of an event.

```
OperID               Start                 End
   141 2014-03-04 19:28:39 2014-03-04 19:33:38
 10502 2014-03-04 02:26:26 2014-03-08 20:09:21
 10502 2014-03-15 00:03:45 2014-03-15 10:03:44
```

I would like to take this data and be able to easily create bins of various types (month, day, hour) 
that show how long, within each bin, the operation was in the affected state.  The Start and End dates often span across hour, day, and month boundaries.

My desired output, if I was binning by day, would look like:

```
OperID  Bin         Seconds
   141  2014-03-04  299
 10502  2014-03-04  77614
 10502  2014-03-05  86400
 10502  2014-03-06  86400
 10502  2014-03-07  86400
 10502  2014-03-08  72561
 10502  2014-03-15  35999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite verbose solution, the loop is hard to get rid of:

Creating new columns

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

df['End_d']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['End']).day
df['Start_d']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Start']).day
```

`print(df)`

```py
   OperID               Start                 End  End_d  Start_d
0     141 2014-03-04 19:28:39 2014-03-04 19:33:38      4        4
1   10502 2014-03-04 02:26:26 2014-03-08 20:09:21      8        4
2   10502 2014-03-15 00:03:45 2014-03-15 10:03:44     15       15
    
[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

`df.dtypes`

```py
OperID              int64
Start      datetime64[ns]
End        datetime64[ns]
End_d               int32
Start_d             int32
dtype: object
```

The bulk of the code:

```py
df1 = df[df.End_d==df.Start_d].loc[:,['OperID', 'Start','End']]  #the obs. of which the duration < 1day
df2 = df[df.End_d!=df.Start_d]                                   #the obs. of which the duration > 1day
```

```py
for i in df2.index:   #Expand it in to multiple rows.
    days=df2.loc[i,:].End_d-df2.loc[i,:].Start_d+1
    start_d_str=df2.loc[i,:].Start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    temp_df=pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict({'OperID': df2.loc[i,:].OperID,
              'Start': pd.date_range('%s 00:00:00'%start_d_str, periods=days),
              'End':   pd.date_range('%s 23:59:59'%start_d_str, periods=days)}))

    temp_df.loc[0,'Start'] = df2.loc[i,'Start']
    temp_df.loc[days-1, 'End'] = df2.loc[i,'End']
    df1=df1.append(temp_df)
```

```py
df1['Bin']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.Start.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))   #Get the YMD only
df1['Seconds']=(df1['End']-df1['Start'])/np.timedelta64(1,'s')                   #Convert to seconds
df1.sort(columns=['OperID', 'Start'], ascending=[-1,-1], inplace=True)
```

Printing our results with `print(df1)`

```py
                  End  OperID               Start        Bin  Seconds
0 2014-03-04 19:33:38     141 2014-03-04 19:28:39 2014-03-04      299
0 2014-03-04 23:59:59   10502 2014-03-04 02:26:26 2014-03-04    77613
1 2014-03-05 23:59:59   10502 2014-03-05 00:00:00 2014-03-05    86399
2 2014-03-06 23:59:59   10502 2014-03-06 00:00:00 2014-03-06    86399
3 2014-03-07 23:59:59   10502 2014-03-07 00:00:00 2014-03-07    86399
4 2014-03-08 20:09:21   10502 2014-03-08 00:00:00 2014-03-08    72561
2 2014-03-15 10:03:44   10502 2014-03-15 00:03:45 2014-03-15    35999
    
[7 rows x 5 columns]
```

Also if you count 1 days as 86400 seconds rather than 86299 seconds, aren't you counting the last seconds twice (in both days)? Minor issue anyway.